# How do I secure traffic between my VM and Application Gateway?

Tags: azure

I have a pretty simple setup with an Application Gateway (AG), that sends traffic to a virtual machine running Ubuntu. The AG is loaded with an SSL certificate. The VM is set up to only allow incoming traffic from the AG, but it's an HTTP connection. This works, but I want to secure the traffic between my VM and AG. I can't find any relevant settings or documentation for this however.

How do I encrypt traffic between an Application Gateway and Virtual Machine? I considered a private link to at least force traffic over the Azure network, but private links only support PaaS products, where a VM is IaaS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your use the private IP of your VM in the backend settings of your Application Gateway. If so, this means that the traffic stays within your VNET and thus on the Microsoft network and also within the same region. You do not not need something like Private Link here.

So the only thing you could potentially do is to SSL-enable the endpoint on the VM and use an encrypted HTTPS connection between AppGW and your VM.

Comment: Yes, the AG and VM share a vnet, but are on different subnets. Considering there are no other VM's running on this vnet, am I right in assuming that SSL is not very useful in my case?

Comment: Very often AppGW is indeed used for SSL termination, meaning you treat the traffic afterwards as safe. If, however, you are concerned about some actor sniffing traffic inside Microsoft's data centers, then adding SSL encryption between your components makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do the same thing as with the api-gateway, load a certificate into de service deployed in the virtual machine and expose the API of this service using SSL protocol so the communication will be encrypted using that certificate.

The way to do it is different depending on which technology you are using to deploy your service. For example, if you are using spring-boot you can see how to do it here
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate

However, you can use mutual-tls if you want that the only service that could connect to your VM's deployed service is the AG.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/access/service-auth/mtls

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out mutual TLS as an option.